# image to blob android

Tags: android, image, blob

I am working in Android appplication.
I want to convert Image stored in **JPG/PNG** format to **BLOB** data type of SQL(SQL Server 2008/10).
Could you give me Java/Android code for that. 
Any type of help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First covert image to bytes of array as shown and save bytes as `blob` in sqlite

```
URL url = new URL(UrlToDownlaodImageFrom);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        InputStream inStr = conn.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream buffInStr = new BufferedInputStream(inStr);
        // Need to check the size of Byte Array Buffer.
        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(500);
        int current = 0;
        while ((current = buffInStr.read()) != -1) {
            baf.append((byte) current);
        }
        byte[] array = baf.toByteArray();
        return array;
```

Comment: Thanks. Is byte array a string representation of image in blob format? Because I don't want to get it stored locally on sqlite. Actually I want image as a blob string(text format) which could be sent in email as attachment.

Comment: @user2151150 so can you accept this answer as it solved your problem

Comment: Actually i was asking about code to convert image directly to blob. I didn't find any function or to convert it.only sql query can do it. but you code helped to convert it into byte array. thanks. if you find any such code to convert into blob it will add to the knowledge. Thanks !